# Make the Plantronics .Audio 326 Headset work with the Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, headset

According the Plantronics website (and I quote directly).

*The microphone plug on our .Audio Analog headsets **will not work on Macs**. It will physically fit into the Mic input jack on a Macintosh, However it will not function. Basically the digital soundcard does not recognize the analog signal coming in from the headset. A way to convert that signal is the Griffin adapter or the DSP50.*

I won't be be purchasing an adapter and will in most likelihood return the item, but on the off chance is their a piece of software out their that could make the two work together?

Comment: only adapter is the way ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately their doesn't appear to be a work around, so I'm having to return the headset.